How can all APIs be refreshed in a React component when any action is triggered?
import AppTextInput from '@/components/form-fields/AppTextInput';
import Iconify from '@/components/iconify/Iconify';
import AppButton from '@/components/templates/AppButton';
import AppDataGrid from '@/components/templates/AppDataGrid';
import AppLink from '@/components/templates/AppLink';
import AppPersona from '@/components/templates/AppPersona';
import TableSkeleton from '@/components/templates/AppTable/TableSkeleton';
import AppTag from '@/components/templates/AppTag';
import AppTitle from '@/components/templates/AppTitle';
import {
  CACHE_KEY_AVAILABLE_PAYROLL,
  CACHE_KEY_GENERATED_PAYROLL,
  CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN,
  CACHE_KEY_POSTED_PAYROLL,
  CACHE_KEY_PROCESSED_PAYROLL,
  PAYROLL_CYCLE_LOCK_ENDPOINT,
  PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN_ENDPOINT,
  PAYROLL_CYCLE_SIF_ENDPOINT,
  PAYROLL_EMP_BY_STATUS_ENDPOINT,
} from '@/constants/payroll';
import useGetAll from '@/hooks/useGetAll';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Divider,
  Grid,
  IconButton,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  Paper,
  Stack,
  Step,
  StepButton,
  Stepper,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import {
  GridColDef,
  GridRenderCellParams,
  GridRowSelectionModel,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import StatusCardList from './status-card-list';
import ProcessPopup, { PAYROLL_UPDATE_PAYLOAD } from './process-popup';
import usePut from '@/hooks/usePut';
import AppDrawer from '@/components/templates/AppDrawer';
import PayView from './payview';
import { useState } from 'react';
import nav from '@/AppLayout/nav';
import APIClient from '@/services/api-client';
import { SearchOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { PAYROLL } from '../payroll-list';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import useUserStore from '@/store/user.store';

export type PAYROLL_PROCESS =
  | 'AVAILABLE'
  | 'GENERATED'
  | 'PROCESSED'
  | 'POSTED';

interface STEP {
  id: PAYROLL_PROCESS;
  label: string;
}

const steps: STEP[] = [
  // { id: 'AVAILABLE', label: 'Available Payroll' }, //included this line by Priti
  { id: 'AVAILABLE', label: 'Available Employee' },
  { id: 'GENERATED', label: 'Generated Payroll' },
  { id: 'POSTED', label: 'Posted Payroll' },
  { id: 'PROCESSED', label: 'Processed Payroll' },
];

function Payrun() {
  const params = useParams();

  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState<number>(0);
  const [rowSelectionModel, setRowSelectionModel] =
    React.useState<GridRowSelectionModel>([]);
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] =
    React.useState<PAYROLL_UPDATE_PAYLOAD>();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [deleteOpen, setDeleteOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const { data, refetch, error, isLoading, isFetching } =
    useGetAll<EMP_PAYROLL_STATUS>(
      PAYROLL_EMP_BY_STATUS_ENDPOINT +
        '?' +
        'payrollCycleId=' +
        params.id +
        '&status=' +
        steps[activeStep].id,
      activeStep === 0
        ? CACHE_KEY_AVAILABLE_PAYROLL
        : activeStep === 1
        ? CACHE_KEY_GENERATED_PAYROLL
        : activeStep === 2
        ? CACHE_KEY_POSTED_PAYROLL
        : CACHE_KEY_PROCESSED_PAYROLL
    );
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetching) {
      console.log('Refetching data...');
    }
  }, [isFetching]);
  const handleRowSelection = (rowIds: GridRowSelectionModel) => {
    setRowSelectionModel(rowIds);

    const rows = data && data.filter((d) => rowIds.includes(d.id));

    if (activeStep === 0)
      setSelectedRows({
        payrollCycleId: params.id!,
        employees: rows?.map((r) => r.id),
      });
    else
      setSelectedRows({
        payrollCycleId: params.id!,
        payrollId: rows?.map((r) => r.payrollId),
      });
  };

  const [menuAnchor, setMenuAnchor] = React.useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);

  const handleMenuClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setMenuAnchor(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setMenuAnchor(null);
  };
  const getActionLabel = () => {
    switch (steps[activeStep].id) {
      case 'AVAILABLE':
        return ['Generate Payroll'];
      case 'GENERATED':
        return ['Post Payroll', 'Delete'];
      case 'POSTED':
        return ['Process Payroll', 'Delete'];
      case 'PROCESSED':
        return ['No Actions needed'];
      default:
        return ['Action'];
    }
  };
  const refetchTableData = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient(); // Get the query client instance
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN);
    console.log('Table data refetched');
    refetch();
  };
  const user = useUserStore((state) => state.user);
  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'firstName',
      minWidth: 200,
      flex: 1,
      headerName: 'Employee Name',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { value, row }: { value?: string; row: any } = params;
        return (
          <AppPersona
            profile={{
              maintext: value + ' ' + row.lastName,
              subtext: '#' + row.empCode,
            }}
          />
        );
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'departmentId',
      minWidth: 200,
      flex: 1,
      headerName: 'Department & Division',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { value, row }: { value?: string; row: any } = params;
        return (
          <Box>
            <Typography
              variant='body2'
              fontWeight={'fontWeightMedium'}
              sx={{ color: 'text.primary' }}
            >
              {value!}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant='caption'
              sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}
              fontWeight='fontWeightMedium'
            >
              {row.divisionId !}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        );
        // return <AppTitle title={value!} subtitle={row.division!} />;
      },
    },
    // {
    //   field: 'salary',
    //   minWidth: 100,
    //   width: 150,
    //   headerName: 'Salary',
    //   renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
    //     return (
    //       <Typography variant='body2' fontWeight='fontWeightMedium'>
    //         INR. {params.value}
    //       </Typography>
    //     );
    //   },
    // },
    {
      field: 'status',
      minWidth: 80,
      width: 150,
      headerName: 'Status',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const val = params?.value?.toUpperCase() || 'NA'!;
        return (
          <AppTag
            variant={
              val === 'GENERATED'
                ? 'ACTIVE'
                : val === 'POSTED'
                ? 'INACTIVE'
                : ''
            }
            text={val}
          />
        );
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'action',
      flex: 1,
      headerAlign: 'center',
      align: 'center',
      headerName: 'Action',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { row }: { row: any } = params;
        return (
          <Stack
            sx={{ width: '70px' }}
            direction='row'
            alignItems='center'
            justifyContent='space-between'
          >
            <AppButton
              sx={{
                color: 'primary.main',
                fontWeight: 600,
                textDecoration: 'none',
                padding: '4px 10px',
                display: 'inline-flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
              variant='text'
              onClick={() => handleOpenDrawer(row?.payrollId)}
            >
              View
            </AppButton>
            {/* <Iconify icon='ic:sharp-more-vert' width={22} /> */}
            {/* <IconButton onClick={handleMenuClick}>
              <Iconify icon='ic:sharp-more-vert' width={18} />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              anchorEl={menuAnchor}
              open={Boolean(menuAnchor)}
              onClose={handleMenuClose}
            >
              {getActionLabel().map((label, index) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick(label)}
                >
                  {label}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu> */}
          </Stack>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
  const [viewTitle, setViewTitle] = useState('');
  const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = useState<string>(''); // New state to track drawer open/close

  const { id } = useParams();
  // Function to open the drawer
  const handleOpenDrawer = (id: string) => {
    setIsDrawerOpen(id);
  };

  // Function to close the drawer
  const handleCloseDrawer = () => {
    setIsDrawerOpen('');
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      setIsDrawerOpen('');
    }
  }, [id]);

  const downloadSif = () => {
    const apiClient = new APIClient(PAYROLL_CYCLE_SIF_ENDPOINT(params.id!));
    apiClient.get(true).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.setAttribute('href', fileURL);
      const dt = new Date();
      const yr = dt.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
      const mn = (dt.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
      const dd = dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');

      const hr = dt.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      const min = dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      const sec = dt.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      link.setAttribute(
        'download',
        `${'0000001145097'}${yr + mn + dd + hr + min + sec}.txt`
      );
      document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

      link.click();
      link.remove();
    });
  };

  const lockPayroll = (payrollCycleId: string) => {
    const service = new APIClient(PAYROLL_CYCLE_LOCK_ENDPOINT + params.id);
    service
      .put({ id: payrollCycleId })
      .then((data) => {
        // Invalidate relevant queries
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN);
        toast.success('Payroll locked !');
        refetch();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Error making employee inactive:', error);
        toast.error('Failed to lock payroll');
      });
  };
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  // const onEdit = (editData: PAYROLL) => {
  //   queryClient.setQueryData<PAYROLL>(CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN, editData);
  // };
  const location = useLocation();

  const { state } = location;
  console.log(state, 'state');
  return (
    <Paper
      sx={{
        border: '1px solid',
        borderColor: 'background.neutral',
        backgroundColor: 'background.paper',
        borderRadius: 2.5,
        m: 4,
        overflow: 'auto',
      }}
    >
      <Grid container direction='row' sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Stack sx={{ height: '100%' }} divider={<Divider />}>
            <Stack
              sx={{ px: 2.5, pt: 2.5, pb: 4 }}
              direction='row'
              justifyContent='space-between'
            >
              <AppTitle
                title={'Payroll Cycle Details  '}
                subtitle={`${state?.dateFrom} - ${state?.dateTo}`}
              />

              <Button
                variant='outlined'
                onClick={() => {
                  if (params.id) {
                    lockPayroll(params.id);
                  } else {
                    console.error('PayrollCycleId is undefined');
                    toast.error(
                      'Failed to lock payroll: PayrollCycleId is undefined'
                    );
                  }
                }}
              >
                <Iconify icon='ic:round-lock' width={18} />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Lock Payroll
              </Button>
            </Stack>
            <Box>
              <StatusCardList />
              <Stepper sx={{ pt: 2, px: 1 }} nonLinear activeStep={activeStep}>
                {steps.map((step, index) => (
                  <Step key={step.label}>
                    <StepButton onClick={() => setActiveStep(index)}>
                      {step.label}
                    </StepButton>
                  </Step>
                ))}
              </Stepper>
              <Box sx={{ mt: 5 }}>
                <Stack
                  px={2}
                  direction='row'
                  justifyContent='space-between'
                  alignItems='center'
                >
                  <AppTitle title={'List of Payrolls'} />
                  <Stack direction='row' spacing={2} sx={{ width: '50%' }}>
                    <AppTextInput
                      startIcon={<SearchOutlined />}
                      placeholder='Search by Request Id, Emp no'
                    />
                    <IconButton onClick={() => {}}>
                      <Iconify icon='mdi:filter-outline' width={18} />
                    </IconButton>
                    {activeStep !== 3 && (
                      <AppButton
                        onClick={() => {
                          setOpen(true); // Open the dialog or popup for the action
                          // Assuming the action is completed successfully and you want to update the table
                          // Call refetch to fetch the latest data from the API
                          refetch();
                          console.log('Refetching data...');
                        }}
                        variant='contained'
                        disabled={!rowSelectionModel.length}
                        disableRipple
                      >
                        {activeStep === 0
                          ? 'Generate '
                          : activeStep === 1
                          ? 'Post '
                          : 'Process '}
                        Payroll
                      </AppButton>
                    )}
                    {activeStep === 3 && (
                      <Button
                        variant='text'
                        onClick={downloadSif}
                        startIcon={
                          <Iconify
                            icon='ic:baseline-cloud-download'
                            width={16}
                          />
                        }
                      >
                        SIF Download
                      </Button>
                    )}

                    {activeStep === 1 && (
                      <Button
                        variant='text'
                        disabled={!rowSelectionModel.length}
                        startIcon={<Iconify icon='ic:delete' width={16} />}
                        onClick={() => {
                          setDeleteOpen(true);
                        }}
                      >
                        Delete
                      </Button>
                    )}
                  </Stack>
                </Stack>
                <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                  {data && !isLoading ? (
                    <AppDataGrid
                      columns={columns}
                      rows={data}
                      rowHeight={75}
                      getRowId={(row: EMP_PAYROLL_STATUS) => row.id}
                      checkboxSelection={activeStep !== 3}
                      onRowSelectionModelChange={(
                        newRowSelectionModel: GridRowSelectionModel
                      ) => {
                        handleRowSelection(newRowSelectionModel);
                      }}
                      rowSelectionModel={rowSelectionModel}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <TableSkeleton columns={columns} />
                  )}
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Stack>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      {selectedRows && (
        <>
          <ProcessPopup
            data={selectedRows}
            process={steps[activeStep].id}
            open={open}
            setOpen={setOpen}
            refetchTableData={refetchTableData}
          />
          {activeStep == 1 && (
            <ProcessPopup
              data={selectedRows}
              process={'DELETE'}
              open={deleteOpen}
              setOpen={setDeleteOpen}
              refetchTableData={refetchTableData}
            />
          )}
        </>
      )}

      <AppDrawer
        header={viewTitle || 'View Leave'}
        open={!!isDrawerOpen} // Use the state to control drawer open/close
        setOpen={handleCloseDrawer} // Pass the close function to the AppDrawer
      >
        {isDrawerOpen && <PayView setTitle={setViewTitle} id={isDrawerOpen!} />}
      </AppDrawer>
    </Paper>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Payrun);

interface EMP_PAYROLL_STATUS {
  id: string;
  payrollId: string;
  payrollCycleId: string;
  title: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  empCode: string;
  departmentId: string;
  divisionId: string;
  salary: number;
  status: PAYROLL_PROCESS;
  payMode: string;
}


Here i already used 'queryClient' for refteching but its not working what is the solution for refresh all api's using queryclient
  const refetchTableData = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient(); // Get the query client instance
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN);
    console.log('Table data refetched');
    refetch();
  };

created function with queryclient but it won't works please help me refresh all api's using query client please correct my code and logic thanks in advance friends,
what is my mistake please also provide what i made a mistake here.

excuse me, tell me what value this const "CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN" is? If its value equals {queryKey: ["something_key"]}, then it is ok, else it is bad and you should correct to {queryKey: ["somethig_key"]}
https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/guides/query-invalidation

export const CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN = [
'payroll',
'cycle',
'payrun',
'list',
];
it is that one you asked

queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey: CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN})
